# UID/GID with sshfs of Linux FUSE

Tags: linux, sshfs, fuse

```
mkdir ~/mnt/2letter
echo PASSWORD | sshfs -o password_stdin www-data@localhost:/var/www/sites/2letter ~/mnt/2letter -o sshfs_sync,cache=no,password_stdin
```

After this:

```
$ ls -ld ~/mnt/2letter/
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 28 21:29 /home/porton/mnt/2letter/
```

I need to access /home/porton/mnt/2letter/ under my UID (`porton`) not as `www-data`, because I am not allowed by file system permissions to modify `www-data` owner files, but need to edit them.

Moreover it seems to have been working with the correct UID with older versions of Linux. Why doesn't it work now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try chucking in the two following options

```
-o idmap=user,uid=<YOUR UID>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, I need also to specify gid=XXX, but why does it works only with numeric IDs

Comment: You will have to ask the author(s) of sshfs that question :)

Comment: in order to discover the numbers behind your uid and gid, you can use the id command. With these numbers you can specifi exactly who is mounting and get the correct rights after that (id -u gives you your uid number and id -g your group (note: @Jeff why did you delete my answer, I consider is was very relevant as many users do not know how to get their id details - is this a place for experts only or for learning things !?)

Comment: @splaisan - are you sure you're talking to the right people?  There's no Jeff in this thread ...

Comment: Hi @tink. Yes i am, and believe me I am not looking for a fight here, I was just very surprised that my previous answer was simply deleted by a Jeff Schaller who I stil see but apparently not you, [here a screenshot](https://ibb.co/V2rKg6w)

Comment: Well ... @splaisan - Jeff was right; as it stood your answer didn't address the question, it would have been a suitable addition to the comments in my response (as it addressed one of the comments here).

Answer (score -1):

Based on @tink 's awnser, we can use uidfile and gidfile to specify multiple id mappings conveniently:

```
sshfs -o default_permissions -o nomap=ignore -o idmap=file -o uidfile=~/uidfile -o gidfile=~/gidfile $user@$dataServer:/home/groups/shared /home/$user/shared/
```

You may use the following to generate uidfile and gidfile (in the remote server of course):

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,3 > uidfile
cat /etc/group | cut -d: -f1,3 > gidfile
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).